# AngularJS DELETE request to my REST webservice is in plain text?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

So I am trying to wire up an AngularJS front-end to a Java Spring back-end using a REST service.

My DELETE requests keep getting the following error (notice the speaker?id=) - Why is it generating speaker?id= instead of speaker/ ?

```
DELETE http://localhost:8082/rest/speaker?id=54200b6b772f1e7b0688307b 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

The code is as follows:

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {
    speakerService.delete(id);
}
```

Angular JS service

```
this.delete = function (id, callback) {

    SpeakerResource.delete({ id: id }, function () {
        callback();
    });

}
```

Angular JS factory

```
app.factory('SpeakerResource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('rest/speaker/:speakerId',
    {
        speakerId: '@speakerId'
    },
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' }
    },
    {
        'delete': { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@speakerId' } }
    }
```

If I use the $http statement then everything works correctly, but obviously I'd like to stick to using the factory as the PUT/POST methods are working fine!

```
    $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/rest/speaker/' + data.id);
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the params object on the delete action or rename the parameter to speakerId, because otherwise AngularJS cant set the url parameter in the resource (your url placeholder is speakerId, but your property is named id)

Comment: Hi, had to do this (change to speakerId) and I also had to remove the quotes '' around the delete name.